# ExtJs Load different data from one store to multiple selects

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, extjs4.2

I have 1 store which serves me the values from a UD field which are the options for the comboxes.

```
Ext.define('freetextOrder.model.comboBoxValues', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'unit', type: 'string'}
        {name: 'comboxid', type: 'int'}
    ]
});
```

now i have to load foreach comboxid an xtype: 'combobox' with the values there are in store. i was hoping there is a way i can set the filters for each combox but the filters get applyed to all comboxes.

How to achive tht except to make a new store foreach combobox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ext 5.x you can use [chained stores](http://extjs.eu/on-chained-stores/), for earlier versions of Ext you have to create separate store for each combo.

Comment: Ye, not really helping with 5.x... we use the 4.2.1 but ok. thy anyway.